# Send Attachment in php without selecting a file

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

`reports/pdf_receipt.php` is the path of my pdf_receipt.
What i want to acchive is when i send the email a download file will also be include. But can i convert `pdf_receipt.php` to `pdf_receipt.pdf`.
Im using FPDF

```
$mailer->AddAttachment( "reports/pdf_receipt.php" , "pdf_receipt.php", 'base64', 'application/octet-stream' );
```

Comment: An attachment isn't run before being attached. You will need to execute the script to produce the report, then attach it to the email. You can then delete the file after the email is sent. You might be able to produce the PDF as a stream and attach it, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: i mean sir i already created a reports and display on a pdf file but its file name is pdf_reciept.php .... do i need to convert php tp pdf

Comment: If you want the recipient's computer to treat it as a PDF, you will need to name it with the proper extension. Rename the file, or edit the code that produces it to use the proper extension. Also, attachments with executable code extensions like ```php``` may cause the recipients email program to mark the email as spam.

Comment: Is the file pdf_reciept.php a php script or a PDF file? If the former, you'll need to execute it. If it outputs a PDF to the browser, you'll need to either pipe it's output to a file, or modify it to save the PDF to a file.

Comment: yes sir the file is pdf_reciept.php when i run in the browser it open in a pdf file format. but  i dont know how can i modify the file to make a .pdf extension thank you

Comment: @JohnEnglish It depends on the source code of the `pdf_receipt.php`. Check the library you are using and change it that the PDF is saved in a file instead. Then you can attach this file to your mail.

Comment: The fpdf library is pretty easy to use and understand. Near the end of the code, it will have a command that renders the PDF. It sounds like the code you have sends the output to the browser (stream). You just need to change a couple of lines to have it write to a file instead. There are probably also a couple of lines that set HTML headers so the browser treats the stream as a PDF instead of HTML, you will need to remove them.